# Access Subforms not showing

Tags: ms-access

I'm picking up on a project that got started a while back by a previous developer, not massively up with Access.

There's a form that has 14 subforms on it, 11 of them work, 3 of them don't, I cannot figure out why the 3 won't load.

I have ensured that DataEntry = No and AllowAdditions = Yes.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Without more detail it's fairly difficult to provide any help with this.  I would start by checking the data sources for the three non-working subforms - are they editable tables\queries?  If so, the problem is probably the configuration of the sub-form.  If they are not editable, the data source is the issue

Comment: Are the subforms themselves not showing up the data within the subforms? In other words: are you seeing no grid at all or empty grids? (assuming that the forms are in Datasheet view)?

Comment: Just a white box is showing, originally I thought it was because there was no data however some of the other forms don't have any data and they're showing just fine.

Comment: Might want to post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Comment: When you [Create a form that contains a subform](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-form-that-contains-a-subform-a-one-to-many-form-ddf3822f-8aba-49cb-831a-1e74d6f5f06b) a Subform Control is added to the main form. The Source Object property of this control stores the name of the Subform. Check it. It might also be empty and added dynamically in the VBA code.